# The Fundamental group of the sphere is connected to a circle

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, solution-verification, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

I have the following question:

> Let X $\subseteq$ $\mathbf{R^3}$ denote the unit sphere with the
> circle in the xy-plane. What is $π_1$(X)?

I think that this is an application of Van-Kampen Theorem. Specifically, consider the open sets $U_1$= X−{N} and $U_2$ =X−{P} where N,P denote the north pole of the sphere and P is a point on the circle , respectively. Notice that the intersection $U_1$ $\cap$ $U_2$= X−{N,P} is path connected and $U_1$$\cup$ $ U_2$=X . We see that $U_1$ deformation retracts onto the circle Thus, $π_1$($U_1$) is $Z$ and $U_2$ deformation retracts onto the sphere Thus $π_1$ ($U_2$) is trivial By Van-Kampen Theorem $π_1$(X)= $π_1$($U_1$)∗$π_1$($U_2$)/N (where N is the normal subgroup generated by identifying paths in the intersection as paths in $U_1$ and $U_2$) so $π_1$(X) is $Z$

Does this seem correct? Any comments or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

> This question was asked in this link but without using Van-Kampen
> Theorem

[Fundamental group of a sphere with a handle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3885164/fundamental-group-of-a-sphere-with-a-handle)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Van Kampen theorem to prove all spheres have fundamental group 0.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118930/van-kampen-theorem-to-prove-all-spheres-have-fundamental-group-0)

Comment: No because its fundamental isomorphic to the set of the integer not 0 but i am not sure how i can show that

Comment: You said that $X$ is the unit *sphere* $=S^2$. Did you mean to ask what the fundamental group of the unit *circle* $=S^1$ is?

Comment: @MatthewNiemiro may be OP means $S^2\vee S^1$. At least that's what I gather from "the unit sphere with the circle in the xy plane" and the rest of the post.

Comment: yes i mean that it like a sphere with handle